# is there a "sic" attribute or tag in html

Tags: html

> The Latin adverb sic ("thus"; in full: sic erat scriptum, "thus was it written") inserted after a quoted word or passage, indicates that the quoted matter has been transcribed exactly as found in the source text, complete with any erroneous or archaic spelling, surprising assertion, faulty reasoning, or other matter that might otherwise be taken as an error of transcription.

Does the current HTML(5) standard have any similar means, other than just writing *(sic)*, to define that a word, phrase or paragraph is deliberately written in this way, so that parsers can be informed of deliberately misspelled words etc. Or are there any plans for including this semantic into HTML5?

Comment: HTML isn't concerned with misspelled words. HTML is basically content-agnostic - it describes the structure of a webpage, and isn't overly concerned with what gets placed between HTML tags.

Comment: There is no specific html code for that as it isn't  really a special character or symbol

Comment: @EatPeanutButter that is not true, HTML also provides ways of defining additional information and semantic meanings to the content. e.g. you can do `<abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr>`, `<p lang="goh">Fater unsêr, thû pist in himile</p>`, `<a href="products.html" title="Retail products shop">Products</a>` etc.

Comment: @fritzmg Not quite. HTML is about structure, not content. The semantics are about the element. A `<nav>` element defines navigation without knowing anything about the content. Same with `<p>`.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't state anything to the contrary.

Comment: `<i>` tag should be used: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/95681/18400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such element. You can look up all HTML elements on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element). You can write `(sic!)` unformatted or italic: `<i>(sic!)</i>`.

It's possible that search-engines that search for grammatical errors exclude quotes. For quotes you can use the following HTML elements:

- `<q>` is used for short inline quotes.
- `<blockquote>` is used for bigger quotes, usually indented.

Comment: Someone was claiming, that search engines might rank your site lower, if it contains grammatical errors - but sometimes those errors might be deliberate - thus it would be important to define that content as such. Personally, I don't think that claim is actually true, but nevertheless I was wondering about whether there is any such semantic element or attribute.

Comment: Thanks, the quote tags seem like the most fitting option :)

Comment: @fritzmg - "Someone was claiming, that search engines might rank your site lower, if it contains grammatical errors". That would be pretty awesome in the multitude of languages that search engines must deal with. Conceivable, I guess, but has the feel of yet another SEO myth. Generally, if a page contained lots of genuine grammatical errors, it wouldn't get linked to much, which would suppress its page rank anyway.

Comment: Yep, it does feel like yet another SEO myth, that a so called "SEO expert" probably made up.